# How to write a script that will use a loop structure to process data file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

I have an input file with the following data:

```
November 400
January 200
June 400
March 200
April 200
May 300
July 400
August 300
September 400
February 300
October 300
December 200
```

I have to make a loop structure that will process the data file line by line, then send it to an output file resulting in this output

```
Month     Sales
-----     -----
January   200
February  300
March     200
April     200
May       300
June      400
July      400
August    300
September 400
October   300
November  400
December  200

Total   show the total

Average show the average
```

I am having issues with getting the data and outputting it properly. I have tried using shell check to clean up the syntax but am having issues. Here is the code.

```
#!bin/bash
awk >>practicefile.output

    BEGIN{
    print "Month\tSales"
    print "-----\t-----"
{ Month[$1] = $2; next }
{ lines[(Month[$1])] = $1 (Month[$1]) $2 }
END {
    for (i=1; i<=7; i++) {
        if (lines[sales[i]])
            print lines[month[i]]
        else
            print month, sales[i]
        fi
            }
    }
```

Comment: Argghhh!  So many things to say!  (1) Before trying to write an entire, functional `awk` script, learn how to write ***an*** `awk` script — there are thousands of examples on this site.  (2) Your curly braces aren’t balanced — you have five `{`s and only four `}`s.  (3) Please indent your code better.  (4) What does `7` have to do with your question?

Comment: Is there a way to write it using a different method? I was just trying to self study with awk, but am having an issue apparently. How else would I go about executing this?

Comment: Oh, I missed an easy one:  (0) The first line should be `#!/bin/bash` — you left out the first `/`.  (Although I actually recommend using `#!/bin/sh` unless you’re doing something that’s bash-specific, which you clearly aren’t.)  But, if you fix that, what happens when you run it?  Do you get any output that gives you a clue as to what you’re doing wrong?  Let me put it a different way — try to write an `awk` script to switch the order of the fields (hint: `print $2, $1`).  You’ve obviously learned something about `awk`; have you learned enough to use it to actually *do anything*?

Comment: You can also use a loop with `while read -r month sale; do`.

Answer (score 1):

I got the desired output

```
Month     Sales
-----     -----
January   200
February  300
March     200
April     200
May       300
June      400
July      400
August    300
September 400
October   300
November  400
December  200

Total   3600

Average 300
```

using the following script (saved as `test.awk`):

```
BEGIN {
    print "Month     Sales"
    print "-----     -----"
}

{ printf "%-9s %s\n", $1, $2 }
{ sum += $2 }

END {
    printf "\nTotal   %s\n", sum
    printf "\nAverage %s\n", sum / NR
}
```

and calling it like `sort -k1,1M input.txt | awk -f test.awk`.

Explanation: `printf "%-9s", $1` adds padding (with spaces) up to 9 characters to the string (`$1`). `sort -k1,1M` sorts the input by month. Not entirely awk but much easier.

Comment: `cat ` *`filename `* `| ` *`command`* is a [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat) — just do `sort -k1,1M input.txt | awk -f test.awk`.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it. (Thank you! I've been doing this wrong since 10 years of using linux.)